# Unable to populate ListView with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist

I'm trying to make an audio recorder for which I want to display a list of recordings done till now.

I'm able to get the list recorded files from my SD card in to an ArrayList, but my app crashes when it tries to populate the list view.

ListRecordings.java is called using an Intent from MainActivity.java.

Here is the for ListRecordings.java:

```
public class ListRecordings extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.listrecordings);
    ListView lv;
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/MyAudioRecorder";

    ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(path);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.filelist);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.textlayout,
            FilesInFolder); 

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // Clicking on items
        }
    });
}



public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if (files.length == 0)
        return null;
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
    }

    return MyFiles;
}
}
```

Here's the code for listrecordings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/filelist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code for textlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

Any help is appreciated.

I've just started with android so excuse me if i made any lame mistakes.

Thanks

Comment: post the stacktrace pls

Comment: what is your error? please post your logcat error here

Comment: I think the problem is the `R.layout.textlayout`, I'm not sure, but I don't think you can pass a xml here, but rather an Id.

Comment: As a wild guess, your app might crash if you try to list an empty directory. Does it work if you return `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` instead of `null` from `GetFiles`?

Comment: Probably you're getting NPE.

Comment: I thinks you missing super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in onCreate().

Comment: Maybe your GetFiles method return null @gabriel is right use Collections.EMPTY_LIST instead

Comment: @Gabriel Negut The directory is not empty, also when I debug the code FilesInFolder contains all the file names in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You missing this line in onCreate()**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: Thanks @Haresh can't imagine how I missed it.

Comment: Glad to help you and if you carefully check your log error then you getting why is it not working.

Comment: For some reason my LogCat was not showing any log at all.
I had to restart Eclipse to get the logs back.
But yes I'll keep this in mind.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this

`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.textlayout, 
   R.id.textview_id_in_textlayout,FilesInFolder);`

I hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.
I tried this but i'm getting and exception as follows:

android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity         {com.idsil.myaudiorecoder/com.idsil.myaudiorecoder.ListRecordings}     did not call through to super.onCreate()